# Why Won't HTML Table Rows Sort Using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

This code does not reorder the display of rows to `c`, `b`, `a` as desired. Changing `table` and `tr` to `div`s (and removing `td`s) does work. Does anyone know why, or a way to keep semantic HTML tables and sort using flexbox?

```css
#results { display: flex; }
#rowa { order: 3; }
#rowb { order: 2; }
#rowc { order: 1; }
```

```html
<table id="results">
    <tr id="rowa"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowb"><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowc"><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If you like LGson's answer please accept it (using green check to the left), if you need something else leave a comment to his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work as between the `table` and `tr` exist a `tbody`, which you either add yourself, or it will be added as an anonymous one.

So in this case it's not the `tr` that becomes flex item, the `tbody` is.

Add `tbody` to your rule and it will work

```css
#results tbody { display: flex; }
#rowa { order: 3; }
#rowb { order: 2; }
#rowc { order: 1; }
```

```html
<table id="results">
    <tr id="rowa"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowb"><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowc"><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Updated

Based on the fact that with `table` this would lay out vertical, and for that to happen with Flexbox, we need to add `flex-direction: column`

```css
#results tbody { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
#rowa { order: 3; }
#rowb { order: 2; }
#rowc { order: 1; }
```

```html
<table id="results">
    <tr id="rowa"><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowb"><td>b</td></tr>
    <tr id="rowc"><td>c</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Interesting that the output is not on separate rows. I wonder if flexbox does not play well with "old school" HTML tables.

Comment: @GregCatalano No, it doesn't, though if you expect a row like layout you need to add `flex-direction: column` (as Flexbox defaults to _row_) ... updated my answer with a second sample

Comment: Thanks. If you have multiple columns, the cells seem to lose vertical alignment because of flexbox. It's off-topic for this question of course. But my goal of using flexbox to sort table rows (and keep it tabular) seems to be out of reach. https://jsfiddle.net/GregCatalano/2efaqxwn/2/

Comment: @GregCatalano That is correct. As soon as you set `display: flex` they stop being tabular data element and start being flex elements. There is way's to make flex elements behave similar to a table, though it is a completely new question. I would also suggest to not use `table` elements at all if you want to involve Flexbox, since you might run into cross browser issues